# using ramda type definition, pipe function throws type error

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I installed type definition file for Ramda (@types/ramda), when I write the following code, no complains:

```
const gt5 = (x: number): boolean => x > 5
const inc = (x: number): number => x + 1
const f = pipe(map(inc), filter(gt5))
console.log(f([1,6,8]))
```

but if I change the order of filter and map:

```
const gt5 = (x: number): boolean => x > 5
const inc = (x: number): number => x + 1
const f = pipe(filter(gt5), map(inc))
console.log(f([1,6,8]))
```

I got the following error:

*(alias) filter(fn: (value: number) => boolean): R.FilterOnceApplied (+4 overloads)
import filter
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'FilterOnceApplied' is not assignable to parameter of type '(x0: unknown, x1: unknown, x2: unknown) => readonly number[]'.
      Types of parameters 'source' and 'x0' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number[] | Dictionary'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Dictionary'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(2172, 9): The last overload is declared here.*

Of cause the code still runs correctly.

How do I fix this error?

I'm using VSCode.

Comment: I would suggest asking in the forums of whatever team maintains your typing file.  Many of the Ramda experts know little of typescript.

Answer (score 2):

`filter` is *supposed to work with both arrays and objects, but typescript gets confused as a result* - from [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/25581#issuecomment-557826772)

So one way to fix this error is:

```
const f = pipe(
  filter<number, "array">(gt5),
  map(inc)
);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Finally found my answer after a few hours of searching. Thank you!